# Sum two variables in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android Studio but I have programmed Java before.
I need to sum two numbers in one activity and then print the result in a new activity, the compiler it's ok but the app force close.
Where is my fault?
Here's my source:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OpenActivity2();


            }
        });
    }

    public void SumAB(TextView tva, TextView tvb, TextView tvsomma) {
        double a, b, somma;
        a = Double.parseDouble(tva.getText().toString());
        b = Double.parseDouble(tvb.getText().toString());
        somma = a + b;
        tvsomma.setText(String.valueOf(somma));
    }

    public void OpenActivity2() {

        TextView result = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView var1 = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView var2 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        SumAB(var1,var2,result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase; class names in PascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `SumAB()` after you launch Activity2 with `startActivity(intent)`; so when the `tvsomma.setText()` is executed it expects to find a `tvsomma` view but it's a part of the first activity which should be in background now.

> I need to sum two numbers in one activity and then print the result in a new activity

You should remove `SumAB()` method and do the below behavior

Here your are trying to display the result at the same activity; if you want to display the result on the second activity, you've to send this sum using

```
double a, b, somma;
a = Double.parseDouble(tva.getText().toString());
b = Double.parseDouble(tvb.getText().toString());
somma = a + b;
intent.putExtra("SUM", somma);
startActivity(intent);
```

And receive this result at `Activity2` using:

```
int somma = getIntet().getIntExtra("SUM", 0); // 0 is the default value
```

Then set this value to some `TextView` at Activity2 with

```
myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(somma));
```

Comment: This is the second activity:
```
int somma = getIntent().getIntExtra("SUM", 0);
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
textView.setText(String.valueOf(somma));
```
and the result is 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in your code.

1. Create a separate java file for another activity.
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) method inside **onCreate()** function in the 
   above mentioned Java file is used to set layout for activity one.

To set view for another activity, you need to create another java file say "sum.java". Here you need to mention again setContentView(R.layout.activity2_main) method inside onCreate() function. **activity2_main** represents the second activity where you want to print value of sum.

2. Instantiate all the UI widgets in a java files respectively.
   In the java file, instantiate TextView var1, TextView var2 and button.
   In the second java file, instantiate TextView result.
   The aim here is, all the UI widgets that you are using in first activity should me 
   mentioned in first file and correspondingly second file should have widgets related to 
   second activity.

You also need to perform type casting while instantiating the variables like:

**TextView var1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); [Down casting is performed here].**

3. You need to use following two functions if you want to send data from one activity to another.

   **putExtra()** method is use for send the data, data in key value pair key is variable 
    name and value can be Int, String, Float etc.
   **getStringExtra()** method is for get the data(key) which is send by above method. 
    according the data type of value there are other methods like getIntExtra(), 
    getFloatExtra()

   Check out this link to get more insight on this topic- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-how-to-send-data-from-one-activity-to-second-activity/